# How can I filter elements of the list based on their index(position) using stream() in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I filter elements of the list based on their index(position) using stream() in Java?
I want to filter every third element (i.e. indices 0, 3, 6, 9,... of a `List<String>`).

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 9 you can use [`IntStream.iterate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) to achieve that:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < list.size(), i -> i + 3)
        .mapToObj(list::get)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you are using Java 8 you can use this:

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 3)
        .limit(list.size() / 3)
        .mapToObj(list::get)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

**Edit:** As Holger pointed out in the comments a more efficient solution would be this:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size() / 3)
        .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i * 3))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: More efficient: `IntStream.range(0, list.size()/3).mapToObj(i -> list.get(i*3)) …`

Comment: @Holger Why is this more efficient?

Comment: It boils down to an internal counting loop rather than a loop evaluating two opaque functions. These could get optimized to the same loop logic if the JVM manages to inline them, but still, the Stream implementation behaves differently for some operations when the size is predictable (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456381/how-can-i-filter-elements-of-the-list-based-on-their-indexposition-using-strea#comment99509211_56456405)).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use an IntStream.

For example, the following will create a `Stream` containing all the `List` elements whose indices are divisible by 3:

```
List<String> yourList = ...
IntStream.range(0,yourList.size()) // IntStream of 0,1,2,3,...
         .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0) // IntStream of 0,3,6,...
         .mapToObj(yourList::get) // Stream<String> of yourList.get(0),yourList.get(3),...
         ...
```

Comment: Of course, with any list where `get` isn't direct access (like a `LinkedList`), this is dramatically less efficient than just looping through the list using its iterator in the boring old-fashioned way. But the question did specify stream... (With direct access lists like `ArrayList`, it's only less efficient, not *dramatically* less efficient.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but no sane programmer would use `LinkedList` anyway. But using `IntStream.range(0, list.size()/3).mapToObj(i -> list.get(i*3)) …` would be even more efficient, as it avoids performing `list.size()` conditionals involving a modulo operation and enables the stream to utilize the known size, e.g. for the terminal operations `toArray`, `count` or for parallel streams. That’s already more efficient than an `Iterator` based loop and can be optimized to the same performance than a counting loop, after inlining.

Comment: @Holger - LinkedList has uses. Just not when you want O(1) access time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and generally not for any algorithm based on the `List` interface (other than acquiring a `ListIterator`). You will rarely find a use case for `LinkedList` without a better alternative. That’s not about the concept of linked lists, but rather this particular implementation class as a member of Java’s Collection framework.